# Smoothen jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-animate

On [my website](http://www.sameetsapra.com) built with Rails 4, I use jQuery's `animate` function. However, it doesn't seem to run very smoothly. In my `application.js`, my code is under `$(window).load`:

Here is a sample of the animate block:

```
$('.background').animate({right: '-2000px'}, 1000, function(){
        $($('nav a.active').attr('href')).css("display","none");
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.photos').css("display","none");
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        hash = $('nav a.active').prop("hash");
        target = document.getElementById(hash.slice(1));
        $('.background').animate({right: '0px'}, 1000, function(){
            $(target).fadeIn(300);
            navFix();
        });
});
```

What can I do to make this smoother? You can view the issue live [here](http://www.sameetsapra.com) by clicking on the navigation links on the left.

Comment: Imagine clearing the background and redrawing the contents of the layer every few milliseconds in a new position. It becomes more resource intensive as the layer size grows larger. Therefore animating a large layer is very heavy on the browser. I believe there is no way you can make it much smoother than what it is now unless you reduce the layer size.

Comment: No, it's definitely possible. I turned off his CSS3 transitions on the .background element and all of a sudden the JS animation was perfectly smooth. What's making it jerky isn't browser performance, it's the clash between CSS3's transition and jQuery's animate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your CSS is fighting your JS (with jQuery). Specifically your transitions are fighting your animation.

In your CSS, you've added a CSS3 `transition` to the `.background` class:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

So any time you change any of your `.background`'s CSS properties that can be transitioned, it's gonna try to use that transition speed. Unfortunately for you, the CSS property `right` is a property that can be transitioned. So when you animate your background with a duration of 1000ms, it's fighting your CSS that wants to do it with a duration of 300ms.

So either use the transition or the jQuery animation, but not both simultaneously.

**Fix 1.** Should fix your problem and give you a duration of 300ms:

```
$('.background').css({right: '-2000px'}, function(){
        $($('nav a.active').attr('href')).css("display","none");
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.photos').css("display","none");
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        hash = $('nav a.active').prop("hash");
        target = document.getElementById(hash.slice(1));
        $('.background').animate({right: '0px'}, 1000, function(){
            $(target).fadeIn(300);
            navFix();
        });
});
```

**Fix 2.** Should fix your problem and give you a duration of 1000ms:

```
/* in your CSS */
.background {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* overriding the transition property that was applied to all*/
  -webkit-transition: right 1s ease; 
  -moz-transition: right 1s ease;
  -o-transition: right 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: right 1s ease;
  transition: right 1s ease;

}

// in your JS
$('.background').css({right: '-2000px'}, function(){
        $($('nav a.active').attr('href')).css("display","none");
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.photos').css("display","none");
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        hash = $('nav a.active').prop("hash");
        target = document.getElementById(hash.slice(1));
        $('.background').animate({right: '0px'}, 1000, function(){
            $(target).fadeIn(300);
            navFix();
        });
});
```